# send delete request to api using fetch and useEffect hook in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, use-effect, restful-url

I'm trying to send a delete request to API using fetch and useEffect hook in react. I want to execute the delete request with the click of a button and pass the id of the specific JSON data that has to be deleted. I'm unable to figure out how how to pass this id to fetch function under the useEffect hook.

```
const Display = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([])

  let deleteJSON;

  const handleDelete = (_id) => {
      deleteJSON = async (id) => {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/users/${id}`, {method: 'DELETE', mode: 'cors'})
      console.log(res.status)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/users', {method: 'GET', mode: 'cors'})
        const jsonArr = await res.json()
        setState((prevState) => {
          return [...prevState, ...jsonArr]
        })
    })();
    
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='display'>
      {
        state.map((json) => {
          const {name, email, phone, _id} = json
          return (
              <div key = {_id} >
                <div>
                  <button onClick={(event) => { handleDelete(_id)} } className="box" >Delete</button>
                  <button className="box">Update</button>
                </div>
                <h2>{_id}</h2>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <h2>{email}</h2>
                <h2>{phone}</h2>
              </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see I've passed the **id** to the **handleDelete** function but I can only call the **deleteJSON** function inside the **useEffect** hook. But inside the useEffect hook, I can't get access to this function.

Comment: Why would you delete it in useEffect?

Comment: because network requests are made under useEffect. Once the data gets deleted the DOM has to be updated. Here, I'm changing the DOM on the delete request.

Comment: Just update state within `handleDelete` page and the component will rerender normally

Comment: well, it worked but could you explain why it did so?

Comment: This is how it should work :) I am not sure I understand your question, but glad that you got it to work

Comment: Looks like I figured out why I shouldn't be running delete request under useEffect hook. You asked a good question, Why would you delete it in useEffect? I mean why the hell I'd wish to re-run the delete function again again like fetch request. useEffect hook is used to run something inside it again and again, every time there is a change in some external factors(depedencies ) or the components re-renders. Our UI is not depending on the deleteRequest, it is depending only on the fetch request. So we don't want to re-rerun the delete request on its own.

Comment: Your question was so important. It had all the answers in it. The answer was when would you use useEffect. Under what requirements. The answer is simple when we want to re-run it every time the component changes or there is some change in the dependencies.

Comment: Thank You, you helped a lot. You made my concepts clear.

Comment: can u post the updated working code @NishantKumar?